# How to get $index of angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs

how can i get a $index of items angular.forEach()?

I want some like this:

```
$scope.data = {
  "name": "foo",
  "info": "bar"
}

angular.forEach($scope.data, function (value, key) {

  console.log($index + ' - ' + value.name + ' - ' + value.info)

})
```

Comment: If my answer helped please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: what about third argument?

Answer (score 5):

If you were iterating through an **array** the second parameter in the function - which in your case is `key` - is the index.

If iterating through an **object**, like you are now, you cannot access an index. You'd have to loop it through with a `for in` loop like so:

```
var i = 0;
for (var key in $scope.data) {
    if ($scope.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // Code and stuff
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of Array of any type we can access to its index like below:

```
anArrayOfMyObjects.forEach(
(element,index) =>{
 console.log('index of current item in array : ' + index)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Function [function (value, key)] ==> Key is the index of the foreach loop.